I am trying to do supervised clustring based upon selected genes
I have integratted data. Now i want to do supervised clustring based upon the list of specific genes(total 1112 genes as character vector). Following is code.
Gene_list
   [1] "Mcc"            "Ncan"           "Thg1l"          "Malat1"         "Frmpd3"         "Rbm47"         
   [7] "Ppcdc"          "Olfr907"        "Snrnp40"        "Igf2bp3"        "Bhlhe41"        "EU599041"      
  [13] "Cst3"           "Ccdc162"        "Tug1"           "Olfr66"         "Mid1"           "Dpysl2"        
  [19] "Csf1r"          "Rps27rt"        "Cask"           "Hook3"          "Sass6"          "Eva1c"         
  [25] "Pi4kb"          "Ppm1h"          "Lin54"          "C1qb"           "Lasp1"          "Rbm4b"         
  [31] "Adap2os"        "B2m"            "Olfr509"        "Dock10"         "Mrpl23-ps1"     "Tnfrsf14"      
  [37] "Olfr1385"       "C1qc"           "P2ry12"         "AW822252"       "Olfr596"        "Tpm3"          
  [43] "Slc10a2"        "Ssbp2"          "Ranbp3l"        "Laptm5"         "Ankrd11"        "Olfr586"       
  [49] "Ccdc152"        "Ctsd"           "CT025600.1"     "Slc25a53"       "AI182371"       "Tmem250-ps"    
  [55] "Dbhos"          "Magi3"          "Ddx23"          "Olfr1305"       "Psap"           "Olfr1120"      
  [61] "Ift80"          "Olfr986"        "Fau-ps2"        "CT025579.1"     "Znrf3"          "Xpnpep1"       
  [67] "Slc39a2"        "Olfr825"        "Irak1"          "Tmem72"         "Vmn1r180"       "Olfr351"       
  [73] "Serinc3"        "Vps39"          "Olfr648"        "mt-Nd5"         "Pisd-ps2"       "Cbx1"          
  [79] "Pecam1"         "Eif2ak2"        "Ltbp1"          "Cx3cr1"         "Olfr64"         "Clasp2"        
  [85] "Pot1b"          "Olfr734"        "Olfr740"        "Psg16"          "Olfr1312"       "Maip1"         
  [91] "Srd5a3"         "Cep112it"       "Skint8"         "Gucy1a2"        "CT009536.1"     "Ostf1"         
  [97] "Neurl3"         "Usp25"          "Orc3"           "Ccdc144b"       "Prr15"          "Slfn9"         
 [103] "Prdm11"         "Vmn1r201"       "CT009480.1"     "Dynlt1c"        "Uvrag"          "Ces2f"         
 [109] "Olfr628"        "Mef2a"          "Nfia"           "Zfp488"         "Slc9a7"         "Pm20d1"        
 [115] "Nox4"           "Lyrm1"          "Meg3"           "CT010456.1"     "Mrgpre"         "CT009757.1"    
 [121] "Crp"            "Trem2"          "Olfr1245"       "Colec12"        "Ppnr"           "CT030182.2"    
 [127] "Zfp979"         "Rps6ka5"        "Olfr1217"       "Olfr1009"       "Fdxacb1"        "Lair1"         
 [133] "Olfr789"        "Thsd7b"         "CT025626.1"     "Olfr767"        "Prkcq"          "Olfr667"       
 [139] "Cenpi"          "Cd34"           "Slfn3"          "Six2"           "Ctsb"           "Sesn3"         
 [145] "Olfr432"        "Zmat2"          "CT025642.1"     "Ipmk"           "Cdkn1b"         "Zfp369"        
 [151] "Vsir"           "CT572985.1"     "BC016548"       "Itga4"          "Olfr466"        "Neil3"         
 [157] "Abcc1"          "Slmapos2"       "Naaa"           "Fh1"            "Prickle2"       "Olfr1273-ps"   
 [163] "Klhl7"          "E2f7"           "Sec11a"         "Rn7s1"          "Rn7s2"          "C1qa"          
 [169] "Olfr173"        "Cd300lf"        "Mpeg1"          "Olfr1316"       "Sox1ot"         "Actn2"         
 [175] "Rab8b"          "Zkscan2"        "Mettl6"         "Cul4a"          "Mad2l1"         "Cep97"         
 [181] "Rdh1"           "Lipe"           "Cd200r2"        "Olfr735"        "Ceacam3"        "Kctd12"        
 [187] "Cntn1"          "Olfr1402"       "Olfr1278"       "Ado"            "Slc29a3"        "Mylk"          
 [193] "Sfi1"           "Noct"           "Alkbh8"         "Tgfbr1"         "Vmn1r6"         "Pvt1"          
 [199] "Tcf7l2"         "Kdsr"           "Hook2"          "Olfr54"         "Olfr1383"       "Dnah17"        
 [205] "Alg9"           "Lpl"            "Rnf212"         "Krit1"          "Olfr49"         "Olfr1220"      
 [211] "Olfr204"        "CAAA01205117.1" "Pfkfb3"         "Olfr1303"       "Kcnj2"          "Rfx7"          
 [217] "Ly6e"           "Sytl4"          "Frg1"           "Olfr1286"       "CT025610.1"     "Mup9"          
 [223] "Acer3"          "Nanos1"         "Tcp11l2"        "Vmn1r90"        "Pde3b"          "Slfn8"         
 [229] "Hmmr"           "Eprn"           "Olfr1330"       "Olfr362"        "Ttc41"          "Olfr1537"      
 [235] "Olfr1129"       "Olfr1505"       "Ano4"           "Olfr1352"       "Atpaf2"         "Senp7"         
 [241] "Olfr1297"       "Tnfrsf11a"      "Olfr600"        "Elmod2"         "Slc35c2"        "Macrod2os1"    
 [247] "Olfr802"        "Cux2"           "Asb13"          "Pikfyve"        "Olfr624"        "Lss"           
 [253] "Kdelr2"         "Eif2a"          "Rdh9"           "Trim37"         "Asb1"           "Rplp1"         
 [259] "Sh2d1a"         "Olfr1175-ps"    "Siglech"        "Ifit1bl2"       "Bbof1"          "Khdrbs2"       
 [265] "Jam2"           "Olfr177"        "Olfr365"        "Ap1g1"          "Casp4"          "Nagk"          
 [271] "Vmn2r-ps54"     "Sorbs1"         "Olfr1160"       "Tsga13"         "D10Wsu102e"     "Neu1"          
 [277] "Aspa"           "Gucd1"          "Panct2"         "Brca2"          "Tmem119"        "Gbp5"          
 [283] "Eif4ebp1"       "Fcgr3"          "Arhgef5"        "Serpine2"       "Cnpy3"          "Tyms"          
 [289] "Mill2"          "Cenpc1"         "Slco2b1"        "Olfr243"        "Olfr1216"       "Vmn1r213"      
 [295] "Olfr829"        "Pi15"           "Olfr709-ps1"    "Il6ra"          "Olfr1269"       "Vmn1r18"       
 [301] "Olfr510"        "Trim24"         "AI838599"       "Slc6a1"         "Tpgs2"          "Cd84"          
 [307] "Olfr1233"       "Zfp280d"        "Olfr1459"       "Cpa6"           "Bora"           "Triml1"        
 [313] "Gpr34"          "Lcp2"           "Rpia"           "H2-K1"          "Olfr75-ps1"     "Lactb2"        
 [319] "Rag2"           "Rpl13a"         "Eea1"           "Tbx5"           "Slamf6"         "Vmn1r173"      
 [325] "Tmem170"        "Tbxas1"         "Sgk3"           "Scmh1"          "Cxcl15"         "Olfr472"       
 [331] "Olfr1310"       "Cd40"           "Chrnb3"         "Ifi208"         "Bmt2"           "Rtp3"          
 [337] "Olfr716"        "Zfp809"         "Hdhd5"          "Lcp1"           "Olfr535"        "Olfr715"       
 [343] "Ankrd44"        "Adam12"         "Socs6"          "Syt17"          "Gas8"           "Speer4b"       
 [349] "Olfr354"        "Cyb5r4"         "Serpina9"       "Esyt2"          "Tmem126b"       "Ube2e2"        
 [355] "Fmo5"           "Mtr"            "Olfr671"        "Olfr1328"       "Olfr1471"       "Clec12a"       
 [361] "Map6"           "Utp23"          "Rassf2"         "Vmn1r72"        "Pde6a"          "Phf14"         
 [367] "Cd59b"          "Svep1"          "Vmn1r9"         "Olfr1262"       "Olfr251"        "Zfp981"        
 [373] "Uba1y"          "Zfp992"         "Cep128"         "Fanci"          "Alg5"           "Acer2"         
 [379] "Maats1"         "Olfr63"         "Zbtb20"         "Ermp1"          "Cab39l"         "Dcdc2c"        
 [385] "Ces2b"          "Clec4a2"        "Olfr1162"       "Ctsz"           "Speg"           "Klf10"         
 [391] "Olfr1173"       "Olfr575"        "Acss3"          "Tmeff2"         "Dtnbos"         "AI839979"      
 [397] "Cd33"           "Comt"           "Ptprc"          "Olfr1020"       "Il5ra"          "Olfr645"       
 [403] "Ryr3"           "Icosl"          "Matn2"          "Tbc1d32"        "Tyrobp"         "Vmn1r209"      
 [409] "Vmn1r169"       "Arid1b"         "Uggt2"          "Lsm6"           "Rnf165"         "Xrcc4"         
 [415] "Hoxc9"          "Nudt12"         "Cdt1"           "Adcy8"          "Pkhd1"          "Olfr554"       
 [421] "D5Ertd615e"     "Slc12a8"        "Kcnj15"         "Maf"            "Olfr851"        "Lamb1"         
 [427] "CT009765.1"     "Pnpla1"         "Scfd2"          "Olfr1226"       "Pign"           "Zfp101"        
 [433] "Sdccag8"        "Olfr898"        "Chmp4c"         "Plod1"          "CT033781.1"     "Mrpl19"        
 [439] "Ralgps2"        "Olfr1321"       "Sirt2"          "Chst1"          "CAAA01139602.1" "Ly86"          
 [445] "Chpt1"          "Olfr341"        "Ldhd"           "Vmn1r83"        "Tigit"          "Muc16"         
 [451] "Skap2"          "Sparc"          "Vmn1r203"       "CT030185.1"     "CT025566.1"     "Plekhs1"       
 [457] "Dnah7b"         "Cenpq"          "Acsm2"          "Tmem241"        "Bin2"           "Olfr804"       
 [463] "Spcs2"          "Vmn1r185"       "Apool"          "Olfr1205"       "CT009754.2"     "Rnaseh2b"      
 [469] "Adi1"           "Gnaq"           "Ostn"           "Plxdc2"         "Dnah6"          "Fcer2a"        
 [475] "Rsu1"           "Slc13a1"        "Ston2"          "Mcoln1"         "Vmn1r214"       "Otog"          
 [481] "Cbx3"           "Sp140"          "CT025642.3"     "Nipal4"         "Olfr506"        "Fndc5"         
 [487] "Olfr93"         "Ciapin1"        "Hes7"           "AL607131.1"     "Mycbp2"         "Mbnl3"         
 [493] "Katnal2"        "2610044O15Rik8" "Dock2"          "Olfr109"        "Scd4"           "Ifi213"        
 [499] "Ptges"          "Idi1"           "Tmod2"          "Olfr1192-ps1"   "Olfr329-ps"     "Olfr571"       
 [505] "BC035947"       "Lockd"          "Awat2"          "Igsf11"         "Cisd3"          "Platr14"       
 [511] "Olfr721-ps1"    "Mylk4"          "Tnfrsf22"       "Stx7"           "Prss30"         "Elmo1"         
 [517] "Abca8b"         "Vmn1r58"        "Olfr1416"       "Rps9"           "Tpk1"           "Slc12a3"       
 [523] "Klhdc7a"        "Pkd1"           "Ccl28"          "CT033774.1"     "Olfr1309"       "Zfp458"        
 [529] "Apol7b"         "Ccdc82"         "Ly6h"           "Bglap3"         "Caps2"          "Vmn1r172"      
 [535] "Prkdc"          "Vmn1r46"        "Rps23"          "Naalad2"        "Cd81"           "Mtfr1"         
 [541] "C6"             "Pld4"           "Pappa2"         "Acbd6"          "Rfx3"           "Olfr1247"      
 [547] "Ntrk2"          "Lingo2"         "Platr10"        "Pcdh15"         "Abhd5"          "Olfr676"       
 [553] "Tfpi"           "Lrp2"           "Csf2rb2"        "Platr32"        "CT009510.1"     "CT030159.1"    
 [559] "Cngb1"          "Olfr46"         "Olfr681"        "Cep162"         "Ncstn"          "Vmn1r77"       
 [565] "Lpcat2"         "Ubtfl1"         "Neurod6"        "Platr15"        "Etfdh"          "CT025538.1"    
 [571] "Dock6"          "Acaca"          "Neil2"          "Olfr1044"       "Adgrv1"         "Olfr536"       
 [577] "Prom1"          "Dcx"            "Olfr859"        "Cracr2a"        "Entpd7"         "Dnajb11"       
 [583] "Pgpep1"         "Abca9"          "Pfas"           "Trmt2b"         "Igf1os"         "Lmbrd1"        
 [589] "Canx"           "Gpr174"         "Lamb3"          "Shprh"          "Olfr1396"       "Olfr1351"      
 [595] "Tpt1"           "Gnaz"           "BC026762"       "Olfr1356"       "Spta1"          "Olfr1250"      
 [601] "Col26a1"        "Cdc42"          "Olfr905"        "Zfp709"         "Rbm45"          "Olfr287"       
 [607] "Slc38a5"        "Rap2b"          "Snapc1"         "Tmx4"           "Piga"           "Ugt3a1"        
 [613] "Hdac9"          "Hspb11"         "Pag1"           "Necab1"         "Pabpc4l"        "Vmn1r198"      
 [619] "Ptgr2"          "Asb18"          "Rab3c"          "CT025619.2"     "Txk"            "Isca1"         
 [625] "Ctsc"           "Sult5a1"        "Zfp300"         "Arsk"           "Tex9"           "Dusp23"        
 [631] "Pde7b"          "Zbtb49"         "Nek11"          "Rplp2"          "Abca12"         "Wdfy4"         
 [637] "Zfp943"         "Svet1"          "Olfr137"        "Gga2"           "Timp3"          "Glrx2"         
 [643] "Zfp689"         "Ddx6"           "Fbxw28"         "Ctla2a"         "Mug1"           "Lamp1"         
 [649] "Svil"           "Olfr668"        "Catsperb"       "Nectin3"        "Olfr2"          "CT025624.1"    
 [655] "Olfr1209"       "A2ml1"          "Olfr1039"       "Crot"           "Polr3k"         "Olfr237-ps1"   
 [661] "BC024139"       "Vsx2"           "Pam"            "Nlrp10"         "Cenpf"          "Cep57"         
 [667] "Vmn1r70"        "Msh4"           "Apaf1"          "Fan1"           "Olfr157"        "Pik3r5"        
 [673] "Tmbim6"         "Fus"            "Smpd3"          "Ccr9"           "Ccnk"           "Nlrp9b"        
 [679] "Mroh2a"         "Brip1"          "Ttn"            "Zfp950"         "Insig1"         "Vps50"         
 [685] "Mndal"          "Dnajc1"         "Prss55"         "Paqr3"          "Cwf19l2"        "Olfr1372-ps1"  
 [691] "Olfr970"        "Kyat1"          "Olfr397"        "Gtpbp4"         "Cct7"           "Dip2b"         
 [697] "Olfr77"         "Kdm5d"          "AW822073"       "Vmn1r81"        "Sqle"           "Olfr56"        
 [703] "Olfr867"        "Cetn4"          "Olfr843"        "Slit2"          "Isoc2a"         "B3gnt8"        
 [709] "Mgam"           "Olfr1238"       "Naip6"          "Camk2a"         "Olfr1161"       "Intu"          
 [715] "Platr9"         "Mettl3"         "Vax2os"         "Ano6"           "Tcf7l1"         "Pygl"          
 [721] "Olfr1156"       "Sntb2"          "Far2os1"        "Dhx33"          "Olfr695"        "Slc7a1"        
 [727] "Kcnq3"          "Klhl24"         "Fubp1"          "C87414"         "Hivep3"         "CT009601.1"    
 [733] "Cltc"           "Zfp125"         "Trim36"         "Adcy10"         "Olfr161"        "Sord"          
 [739] "Iars"           "Nyx"            "Stx4a"          "Lrrfip1"        "Grm5"           "Mecomos"       
 [745] "C4bp"           "Il18rap"        "Nin"            "Olfr1260"       "Mertk"          "Dicer1"        
 [751] "Vps35"          "Alg6"           "Slc35a3"        "Usp28"          "Nckap5"         "Olfr607"       
 [757] "Lyn"            "Col14a1"        "Cyfip1"         "Olfr1346"       "Dnah7c"         "Fam124a"       
 [763] "Mtus1"          "Cp"             "Msto1"          "Gss"            "Gpr149"         "Usp17la"       
 [769] "Rps15a"         "Atm"            "Fam32a"         "Prrg1"          "Senp1"          "Cebpg"         
 [775] "Olfr1048"       "Nav3"           "Terf2ip"        "St14"           "Ufl1"           "Slitrk2"       
 [781] "Olfr1028"       "Med16"          "Olfr845"        "Cubn"           "Rplp0"          "Dnah7a"        
 [787] "Mcmdc2"         "Pax1"           "Agk"            "Dnah14"         "Vmn1r76"        "Tanc2"         
 [793] "Zdhhc6"         "Lacc1"          "Nek7"           "Trim30b"        "Klhl20"         "Olfr381"       
 [799] "Rex2"           "Frem1"          "Abca13"         "BB123696"       "Ankef1"         "Pirt"          
 [805] "Atp10b"         "Ccdc148"        "Olfr1115"       "Fam117b"        "Mpdz"           "Dlx6"          
 [811] "Med17"          "C2cd3"          "Stt3a"          "Smo"            "Zfp429"         "Pole2"         
 [817] "Marf1"          "Tcte2"          "Olfr887"        "Fyb"            "Lrrc7"          "Otx1"          
 [823] "Enpp3"          "Zbed4"          "Mettl13"        "Spry2"          "Ercc6l"         "Zfp780b"       
 [829] "Gpatch2"        "AI662270"       "G3bp2"          "Sik1"           "Arhgap26"       "Nup210"        
 [835] "Sis"            "Kirrel3os"      "Fermt1"         "Ms4a7"          "Vmn1r73"        "Brpf1"         
 [841] "Dcst1"          "Plekhm3"        "Man2a1"         "Cd8a"           "Carmil1"        "Trim27"        
 [847] "Prl7d1"         "Acadsb"         "Glmp"           "Rgs3"           "Trpm1"          "Fcgr2b"        
 [853] "Ercc8"          "Olfr1564"       "Nipal3"         "Olfr1381"       "Olfr981"        "Abcc2"         
 [859] "Ccdc30"         "Cdc123"         "Birc5"          "Tmem260"        "Frrs1"          "Samd14"        
 [865] "Kl"             "Heatr5a"        "Olfr678"        "Trim56"         "Ogdhl"          "Nup205"        
 [871] "Cyb5r3"         "Pid1"           "Gnb4"           "Col25a1"        "Myo1b"          "Coro7"         
 [877] "Rdh12"          "Zfp994"         "Olfr801"        "Hibch"          "Cnga1"          "Appbp2"        
 [883] "Ncf1"           "Dok5"           "Adcy4"          "Ap4m1"          "Ints6"          "Daam1"         
 [889] "Isy1"           "Pycr1"          "Tspan3"         "Synpo2"         "Olfr720"        "Cct6a"         
 [895] "Adgrd1"         "Olfr1116"       "Dhx40"          "Dtna"           "Ttll5"          "Olfr487"       
 [901] "Olfr338"        "Olfr1509"       "Ispd"           "Bnc2"           "Gvin1"          "Otoa"          
 [907] "Parp11"         "Gsap"           "Nt5e"           "Depdc5"         "Dnah5"          "Pcnx"          
 [913] "Olfr808"        "Hectd2"         "Crb1-ps"        "Zfp141"         "Plrg1"          "Rps11"         
 [919] "Rhox8"          "Cyp2j5"         "Phxr4"          "Pzp"            "Ermap"          "Vmn1r197"      
 [925] "Fam169b"        "Ccdc138"        "Olfr273"        "Zfp738"         "Col4a1"         "Kdelc2"        
 [931] "Olfr414"        "Ppfia2"         "Zfp932"         "Tnfaip8"        "Tmem254c"       "Pard3"         
 [937] "Zufsp"          "H2-DMb2"        "Olfr525"        "Zzz3"           "Lrrc3"          "Reg2"          
 [943] "Recql"          "Ivns1abp"       "Pnpla8"         "Nsf"            "Ctcfl"          "Opcml"         
 [949] "Emc9"           "Arpc2"          "Kntc1"          "Pdss2"          "Trim52"         "Rps5"          
 [955] "Tbc1d14"        "Clcc1"          "Chd9"           "Pigx"           "Actr2"          "Cr2"           
 [961] "Klf3"           "Rrm1"           "Itga2"          "Rnpep"          "Zfp871"         "Hacl1"         
 [967] "Cenph"          "Myo1g"          "Irgm1"          "Olfr1178"       "Olfr806"        "Clec2e"        
 [973] "Otogl"          "Pon2"           "AI314278"       "Ildr1"          "Rhno1"          "Vmn1r218"      
 [979] "Ddx58"          "Vmn1r199"       "Pmf1"           "Plce1"          "Casp6"          "Psd4"          
 [985] "Olfr1423"       "Nbas"           "Kpna1"          "Oca2"           "Spag9"          "Olfr1501"      
 [991] "Jak1"           "Oas1b"          "Vmn1r175"       "Dhodh"          "Ttk"            "Thrb"          
 [997] "Ulk2"           "Tacr1"          "Zgrf1"          "Olfr914"       
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 112 entries ]

DefaultAssay(data_integrated) <- "integrated"
data_integrated <- RunPCA(data_integrated, 
                features = Gene_list,
                approx=F, npcs = 30)
Warning: The following 1012 features requested have not been scaled (running reduction without them): Mcc, Ncan, Thg1l, Malat1, Frmpd3, Rbm47, Olfr907, Snrnp40, Igf2bp3, Bhlhe41, EU599041, Cst3, Ccdc162, Tug1, Olfr66, Mid1, Dpysl2, Csf1r, Rps27rt....

data_integrated <- RunUMAP(data_integrated, features = Gene_list, dims = NULL)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': subscript out of bounds

I am not sure should i scale data(as it is SCTtransformed data). and which default assay should be used.although i tried all different assays.
thanks in advance.
Huma
I want to do supervised clustering based upon the list of genes(around 1000).
But not successfull
